# How can I use another class in my PHP 5.6 __autoload() declaration?

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

I have a `messageService` class that I'm instantiating like this:

```
require_once("./classes/messageService.class.php");
$messageService = new messageService();
```

THEN

I want to use the `$messageService` object in my `__autoload` method which looks like this:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    $fileName = "./classes/" . $className . ".class.php";
    require_once($fileName);
    $messageService->logNotice("Loaded File: " . $filename);
}
```

BUT

When I run the code I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined variable: messageService iin /var/www/html/beta.gmtools/api/index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function logNotice() on null in /var/www/html/beta.gmtools/api/index.php on line 17

Which I'm assuming is because `$messageService` isn't in scope?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: When I change `$messageService = new messageService();` to `global $messageService = new messageService();` the server throws a 500 error.

Comment: The error means that your `$messageService` is not defined anymore as an object. You have probably done something wrong with your variable scope. Some documentation: [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$messageService` is not local to the autoload function. While this isn't the best way to handle it, you can use a `$GLOBALS` to get to it

```
function __autoload($className) {
    $fileName = "./classes/" . $className . ".class.php";
    require_once($fileName);
    $GLOBALS['messageService']->logNotice("Loaded File: " . $filename);
}
```

Another way to do this is to use a class with the [__invoke](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke) magic method. It's preferred you do this with [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) but it should work with `__autoload`

```
 class Loader {
       /** @var messageService */
       protected $message;

       public function __construct() {
             require_once("./classes/messageService.class.php");
             $this->message = new messageService();
       }

       public function __invoke($className) {
             $fileName = "./classes/" . $className . ".class.php";
             require_once($fileName);
             $this->message->logNotice("Loaded File: " . $filename);
       }
}

$autoload = new Loader();
spl_autoload_register($autoload);
```

The advantage here is that

1. You're not globalizing anything
2. You're keeping the same instance of your `messageClass`

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have two options:

- Use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) inside your autoload function to be sure it is scoped properly
- Change your `$messageService::logNotice` method to be [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods)

To use a global `$messageService`:

```
require_once("./classes/messageService.class.php");
$messageService = new messageService();

function __autoload($className) {
    // This is where you tell the current scope you want to reference
    // the global variable
    global $messageService;
    $fileName = "./classes/" . $className . ".class.php";
    require_once($fileName);
    $messageService->logNotice("Loaded File: " . $filename);
}
```

To change your method to be static:

```
class messageService
{
    public static function logNotice($msg) { /** **/ }
}

// Be sure the class is manually included first
require_once '/path/to/messageService.php';
function __autoload($className) {
    $fileName = "./classes/" . $className . ".class.php";
    require_once($fileName);
    // Note you're not using a variable here, you're calling the class
    messageService::logNotice("Loaded File: " . $filename);
}
```

I would argue in favor of the second approach, simply because it avoids the use of a global variable.  The downside is that you lose the ability to have continuous state as represented by instance variables inside of your `logNotice` method throughout the entirety of your script, since you will not have a `messageService` instance.